# Is there a C++/win32 library function to convert a file path to a file:// URL?

Tags: c++, winapi

I have an `LPTSTR` for a file path, i.e. `C:\Program Files\Ahoy`.  I would like to convert it to a `file://` URL that I can pass to ShellExecute in order to start the system's default browser pointing at the file.  I don't want to give the path to ShellExecute directly since file associations may result in it being opened by something other than a web browser.  The path is arbitrary, and may contain characters that need to be escaped.

Is there an existing library function, along the lines of Python's urllib.pathname2url, that does this translation?  This can be done via the Uri class in .NET, but I haven't found anything for plain win32.

Comment: can't you start a browser giving it the file location as an argument ? There must be a WMI call to get the default browser executable path .

Comment: Did you mean urllib.pathname2url?  Worst case is it doesn't look hard to translate that code: http://svn.python.org/view/python/trunk/Lib/nturl2path.py?view=markup

Comment: You know, if I put a `file://...` URL that points to a txt file into the Start/Run dialog, it opens notepad not a web browser.  You may need to find the system's default browser from the registry and run it directly instead.

Comment: @Roger: Sorry, you're right of course; it's pathname2url. I've corrected that in the question.

@Tim: Interesting; it worked as I expected in some initial tests, but you're right, a text file does open in Notepad. I'll have to see what's going on; hopefully I'm not going about this the wrong way. Thank you for pointing that out.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's the `UrlCreateFromPath` API:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb773773%28VS.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 3):

There's an entire path handling library within Win32. It's called [Shell Path Handling Functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb773559(VS.85).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Surely it just comes down to replacing the "\" with "/" and adding file:// on the front??

Comment: If you're not thinking about edge-cases you're not doing it right, and there are some for this question, though not too many.

Comment: I'm obviously NOT thinking of edge cases .. would you care to enlighten me? :)

Comment: Character escaping, for one.  The set of characters allowed in a path is not the same as the set allowed for URLs.  For example, a space would need to be translated into either "+" or "%20".

Comment: Also UNC paths which have their own convention: `file:///C|/path/filename`

Comment: yes, and other problems listed at http://blogs.msdn.com/ie/archive/2006/12/06/file-uris-in-windows.aspx

Comment: Interesting :) Cheers guys.  I've always found no problems with the spaces thing (for example), i've always found it got auto appended.  Fair points though :)